# Calculating volume using polygon instead of contour line in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, volume, lakes

What I'm attempting to do is calculate the volume of a lake using a polygon I created by classifying an image for water. I then extracted the polygon from the classification process. What I'm left with is a polygon showing the surface area of the water. I have a DEM of the lake. How do I determine the amount of water this lake contains? I don't want to use a contour line if I dont have to because the heights vary at the edges of the lake.

This is with ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: I think I may have found my solution. I converted the raster dem to a TIN and I'm trying to use the polygon volume tool. Except, I'm not sure what to put for the height field....
in_height_field
The field in the polygon's attribute table that defines the height of the reference plane used in determining volumetric calculations.
String

Comment: If your question has changed please use the [edit] button beneath it to revise it. Potential answerers may not have time to read comments.

Answer (score 2):

**I assume that what you call “DEM of the lake” is DEM of lake bottom and surrounding area.**

If this a case, it is a few steps procedure main ones being calculation of lake bank altitude and average lake depth.

- Convert lake polygon to polyline, using feature to line tool
- Set environment settings snap raster to DEM, cell size = one for DEM
  and convert polyline to raster using any numeric field, output to
  raster “BANK”. Use raster calculator expression:

  Con(~IsNull(”BANK”),”DEM”)

Output to raster “bankZ”.

- Right click on bankZ, SOURCE and scroll to see mean value. This is
  **average altitude of lake bank** (meanZ).
- Create numeric field in polygon and populate it by meanZ. Convert
  polygon to raster using that field, output “surfaceZ”.
- Use    raster calculator to calculate lake depth accounting for 
  imperfections in DEM and lake delineation.

  Con(“surfaceZ”>”DEM”, “surfaceZ”-“DEM”,0)

Mean value of output is **average lake depth**. Now you can compute lake volume because lake area equal area of your polygon. Be careful with units